# Change of file extension in jam script

Tags: c++, windows, cross-platform, bjam, jam

How can i change extension from an input files in jam script. On linux box i have following working code -

```
for local var in $(objFiles)
{
    local objName = [ SHELL "var1=$(var); echo ${var1%.cpp}.obj" ] ;
    obj $(objName) : $(var) : $(properties) ;
}
```

1st line within for loop picks cpp file name and change its extention from `<File>.cpp` to `<File>.obj`. I need to covert these changes compatible to windows platform. I think some module in boost build process would have provided some way to do this but google search in this didnt helped much.

What changes should i do in above code so that `objName` would contain obj file extension and these changes remains compatible across platform (specially win/ linux).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Boost.Jam, but I suspect it just works the same way as in the regular Jam. There are several selector/replacement operators you can apply on variables. In this case you want to use `S=` for changing the file name suffix:

```
local objName = $(var:S=.obj) ;
```

In the regular Jam there is a pre-defined OS-dependent variable `SUFOBJ` which should be used instead of hard-coding ".obj". Not sure, if it is available in Boost.Jam as well. If so, you can use:

```
local objName = $(var:S=$(SUFOBJ)) ;
```